# Rolling out dough

Tags: dough

Looking for a process to speed up rolling out dough to be  used for cheese Pockets or fruit pockets . We're using an eighth of a cup of dough and we want to flatten it so that it can be filled flipped over and sealed, looking for a faster process than by hand,

Comment: What kind of dough are you working with?

Comment: Maybe a pasta roller?

Comment: 1/8 cup of dough?  are you rolling out each one individually?

Comment: How many are we talking about?  Are you making a few dozen or a few thousand?  If you're talking about thousands or even hundreds on a regular basis, you might want to look into getting a sheeter.

Comment: And another thought on mass production -- I've been to mexican restaurants where they have machines that produce flour tortillas.  It makes a little ball of dough, flattens it out, drops it onto a spinning griddle, knocks it over onto another one, then they slide out.  You would only need up through the flattening out part.

Answer (score 5):

A small tortilla press seems like it would accomplish what you want.

[image: torrilla press]

They make quick work of flattening dough and are fairly inexpensive.

Answer (score 3):

A pasta roller can come in handy for other dough rolling applications.  In your case you could roll a sheet and use a ring to cut circles.

Answer (score 2):

I also thought of a pasta roller too but not everybody has one. If you don't, since you already know how thick your rolled dough needs to be and the diameter of each piece, why not roll out a large sheet and then quickly cut each piece like you would a cookie. You wouldn't need to measure out 1/8th cup of dough each time either, further saving time. A glass is often suggested for cutting out larger circles but I find washed empty cans from food cut better and there is no inner slope where dough can hold on.

If you don't mind your cheese or fruit pockets being triangle shaped, you could make them even faster by cutting the whole sheet into squares (a grid pattern) using a pizza cutter or sharp knife instead.

I'm all for time and effort saving tricks when I cook. What I would do might not be what you would though.